# Intersection of arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy, intersection

I need to compute the intersection of two arrays, G and P, but I keep getting errors or empty answers. Below is the code used to make the arrays.

```
L = 1000
n = 15
sigma = 1.3
X = np.random.randn(L)
Y = sigma*(np.random.randn(L))
G = []
P = []
for i in range(L):
    m = np.random.randint(0,L,n)
    R = np.sum((X[m]-np.mean(X))*(Y[m]-np.mean(Y)))
    S = np.sum((X[m]-np.mean(X))**2)
    K = R/S
    M = np.mean(Y) - K*np.mean(X)
    G.append(K)
    P.append(M)
```

I'm following examples I've found online to find the intersection of G and P. I have verified that the examples work in a separate test script, but they won't work for this one.

The command

```
print(G & P)
```

gives me

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'

The command

```
print(np.array(G) & np.array(P))
```

gives me

> TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

The command

```
print(set.intersection(set(b2), set(a2)))
```

gives me an empty set: `set()`

What am I doing wrong? Why does my test script work while this one does not?

Comment: Why did you not use `set(G) & set(P)`?

Comment: `set(G) & set(P)` gives me another empty set: `set()`

Comment: Why did you expect that the intersection is not empty?

Comment: There should be some kind of intersection of the two arrays. If I plot their histograms, P is entirely contained with G.

Comment: That doesn't mean that they contain the same values. Histograms typically are using intervals, not discrete values.

Comment: Oh, right. I think you just answered my question.